# How to delete rows of data where a string is found?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro to delete lines from csv or txt files if a user input string exists.

I declared variables for `File1`, `File2`, `File3` etc. that are based on an input text file which always has different filepaths that need to be searched. This part of the code works.

The next part of the code is supposed to look at the file extension of each file and based on this call the correct procedure.

When I ran the code on some files where the first four were .csv and the fifth was .txt, nothing happened in the csv files but the fifth file was saved as the fourth file.

Code snippets below:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim myOutput As String:
myOutput = "G:\Team Drives\Technology Team\Data Management\Admin\GDPR\tempoutput.txt"

If File1 <> "" Then
    If Right$(File1, 3) = "csv" Then
        Workbooks.Open File1
        Call cleanCSV
    Else
        Open File1 For Input As #1
        Call cleanTXT
        File1.Close
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Kill myOutput
    End If
End If

If File2 <> "" Then
    If Right$(File2, 3) = "csv" Then
        Workbooks.Open File2
        Call cleanCSV
    Else
        Open File2 For Input As #1
        Call cleanTXT
        File2.Close
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=File2
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Kill myOutput
    End If
End If
```

(above carries on to allow for more files to be searched)

```
Sub cleanCSV()

'removes rows in csv files where the entered email is found
Dim Cell As Variant
Dim SrchRng As Range
Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
lastIndex = SrchRng.Rows.Count
For i = lastIndex To 1 Step -1
    For Each Cell In SrchRng.Rows(i).Cells
        If Cell.Value = SrchStr Then
            Debug.Print
            Cell.EntireRow.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub


Sub cleanTXT()

Dim str As String

'removes lines in text files where the entered email is found
Const myOutput As String = "G:\Team Drives\Technology Team\Data Management\Admin\GDPR\tempoutput.txt"
Open myOutput For Output As #2
Do Until VBA.EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, str
    If InStr(1, str, SrchStr) = 0 Then
        Print #2, str
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing different bits of the same process in different subroutines, and relying on the activeworkbook being the right one, so it's no wonder it's getting the wrong file. Switch your top code into the form

```
If File1 <> "" Then
    If Right$(File1, 3) = "csv" Then
        CleanCsv File1
    Else
        cleanTXT File1
    End If
End If
```

Now put all the rest of the code into the two subroutines:

```
Sub CleanCSV(filetoclean as string)
Dim wb as workbook
set wb = Workbooks.open(filetoclean)
Dim Cell As Variant
Dim SrchRng As Range
Set SrchRng = wb.sheets(1).UsedRange
'etc....
wb.close
end sub
```

and

```
Sub CleanTxt(filetoclean as string)
Open Filetoclean For Input As #1
Dim myOutput As String:
myOutput = "G:\Team Drives\Technology Team\Data Management\Admin\GDPR\tempoutput.txt"
etc...
```

As a general principle a file should be closed by the same routine that opened it, and you should always explicitly pass pointers to workbooks as arguments - don't rely on the activeworkbook still being the one you want when your routine gets called.

Comment: Thank you... I will give this a go

Comment: I've done exactly as suggested, but now running the code gives me the error "ByRef argument type mismatch" and highlights **File1** after `cleanCSV File1`

Comment: File1 is a string? If you've already opened it as a textstream then you'd get that error but the main routine shouldn't be doing that. Try running using F8 to step through and see what the value of File 1 is.

Comment: For some reason now File1 is being evaluated as no value, same for File2. But the following files have the correct filepath. It was working fine earlier (and I haven't touched that code), is there an obvious reason this could happen?

Comment: What code do you use to set File1, and how is it Dimmed?